# JavaScript OOP and Reflection - Are there any (non-trivial/ugly hack) ways to call a 'private' method from outside a class itself?

Tags: javascript, oop, reflection

Are there any (non-trivial/ugly hack) ways to call a 'private' method from outside a class/module itself?

Please don't ask why I need this.

Just my personal curiosity and trust in power of doing anything in JS :)

```
function Module () {

  var privateMethod = function () {
    alert('1');
  };

  var publicMethod = function () {
    privateMethod();
    alert(2);
  };

  return {
    pm: publicMethod
  };
}

var m = new Module();
m.pm(); // can i call m.privateMethod() here somehow?
```

Comment: No, but maybe it shouldn't be private then?

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME**

---

So you've been warned, now look at this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxutqoqo/); I've replaced all the alerts with `console.log()` for the greater good):

```
var methodName = 'privateMethod';
var mSource = Module.toString();
var methodPattern = new RegExp(methodName + '\\s*=\\s*function[^]*?\\{([^]+?)\\};');
var privateMethodSource = mSource.match(methodPattern);
var privateMethodRebuilt = new Function([], privateMethodSource[1]);
privateMethodRebuilt();
```

It's one possible way to do this with HUGE number of restrictions. First, this particular snippet doesn't even try to parse the arguments, assuming that the method in question doesn't need any. Second, you won't be able to access the other private variables defined within the Module (as the code rebuilds only the particular function, not the environment).

Surely, you can take it further - and rebuild the Module itself, making the target method public (for example, by adding the private function into the exposed methods' list). The question is, WHY on Earth do you even think about needing such thing as using the private method outside the module?

Comment: `WHY on Earth do you even think about needing such thing.`

Just to be sure that one can do anything using JS, and there is nothing private in JS world ;)

Comment: BTW I'm looking for a generic way to enumerate and 'publify' all private methods of any given JS object instance having class methods code still working :) And still pretty sure it's possible in JS world

Comment: @Ruslan Just because you keep harping on "Im sure this is possible" doesnt make it possible.

Comment: @Jamiec don't say it's impossible just because you don't know how :)